# How to store a variable in an array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have data from a form submission stored in a variable called `$post_data`. When I do `print_r($post_data);` I get the following array:

```
Array
(
    [element_3] => John Doe
    [element_2] => john@example.com
    [element_14] => City
    [element_15] => Country
    [form_id] => 1
    [submit] => Submit
);
```

I want to store some of the fields in another array to pass to another script. Will my code below work? If not, how do I fix it?

```
$submitted_data = array(
    'Fields' => array(
        array(
            'Key' => 'Name',
            'Value' => $post_data['element_3']
        )
        array(
            'Key' => 'Email',
            'Value' => $post_data['element_2']
        )
    )
)
```

Also, a PHP noob question, do I need another comma (`,`) in between the Name and Email array?

Thanks!

Comment: `do I need another comma (,) in between the Name and Email array?` Yes, you do. Other than that, your solution looks fine.

Comment: `will my code below work ?` did you even try to test it before asking ?, and yes you need the comma as it it the separator between array elements.

Comment: I agree with Serty, indeed. Don't be scared to just try. And make sure you have enabled displaying of errors (only in your testing environment!) and set `error_reporting` to a decent level (`E_ALL`).

Comment: Why don’t you give your parameters meaningful names like “name” and “e-mail” rather than “element_3” and “element_2”?

Comment: Yes it will work, provided you add a comma in between the Name and Email Array

Comment: Thanks guys, I did try it but the data wasn't passed to the 2nd script for some reason. I think there's a problem with the 2nd script.

Comment: @Gumbo the parameters are set by the form software, not by myself..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure why you would want to do this, but depending on the field name you can consider using loops to help automate the entire process.

```
$field_map = array(
    'element_3'  => 'Name',
    'element_2'  => 'E-mail',
    'element_14' => 'City',
    'element_15' => 'Country'
);

$submitted_data = array('fields' => array());    
foreach ( $field_map as $key => $label) 
{
    $submitted_data['fields'][] = array(
        'key'   => $key,             // e.g. element_2
        'label' => $label,           // e.g. E-mail
        'value' => $post_data[$key]  // e.g. john@example.com
    );
}
```

This separates the storage/mapping of key/label pairs from the part which processes it, making it easier to maintain and modify in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Another way might be (depending on how "fixed" the second script is, if you can alter it).

```
$submitted_data['Name']=$post_data['element_3'];
$submitted_data['Email']=$post_data['element_2'];
```

To get a result more like the one in your question:

```
$submitted_data['Fields']['0']['Key']='Name';
$submitted_data['Fields']['0']['Value']=$post_data['element_3'];
$submitted_data['Fields']['1']['Key']='Email';
$submitted_data['Fields']['1']['Value']=$post_data['element_2'];
```